# Posting variable in Ajax to PHP page and getting no response

Tags: php, ajax

I am using ajax to post data to a php page but the response does not return.

```
$('#card_list select').live('change', function() {
    var productID = $(this).attr('value');
    var divID = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "inc/change_thumbnail.php",
            data: "products_id="+productID,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(productID);
                alert(divID);
                $("#"+divID).attr("src", response);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert('Sorry, no thumbnail for product');
            }
        });
})
```

on the php page is the following

```
<?php
$products_id = $_GET["products_id"];
echo "img/products/thumb/".$products_id.".jpg";
?>
```

it is supposed to swap a products thumbnail. but the $product_id variable is not picked up.

Comment: Look at the jQuery documentation to see how to pass data with your AJAX requests. Also you are sending a POST request while in PHP you are using $_GET.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are sending the data using POST and trying to grab it on the PHP page with GET.

Changing $products_id = $_GET["products_id"]; to $products_id = $_POST["products_id"];

Would be a good start.